# rails lazy load of model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, lazy-loading

Normally rails loads data with a :select => "*" from the database. I know I could change this. But I'd like to go another way: always only select "id" and load the attributes automatically later on when they are needed.

Example:
accessing user.description should if it's been loaded yet. if not, trigger a "SELECT description FROM users WHERE id=#{self.id}" and set it.

Anyone know if there's a rails plugin which does this? Or how to implement it?

Thanks,
Corin

Comment: I wouldn't bother doing this. If you have a table/model with so many columns you need this then you need to re examine your app design.

Comment: Similarly, if you've got enough columns for this to be a problem, surely you're going to have a problem generating one SQL query for every attribute in every model?

Comment: The big advandage would be that the individual attributes could be fetched by a much faster key/value storage like memcache oder couchdb. I wonder how big sites like facebook etc. manage their caching while still maintaining data integrity (foreign_keys seem to be impossible with such huge dabasets?)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Rails plugins that does exactly this [lazy_columns](https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/lazy_columns). Notice that a much better approach is to create a new model with the big columns you want to load on demand (since Rails load related objects lazily by default).

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search turned up [this](http://refactormycode.com/codes/219-activerecord-lazy-attribute-loading-plugin-for-rails), but I'm with glongman.  I can't imagine what kind of performance issue would require this...

Answer (score 0):

It is wise to just refactor your main "huge blob" fields into a separate model (like BookBody) which is usually not needed when operating with models in bulk. Alternatively, you can use the `:select` option on finders

```
 BookWithHugeBlobOfText.find(:first, :select=>"only,small,columns")
```

Records selected that way will be readonly since the Rails philosophy says (and rightfully so!) that you need to have *all* data on the model to validate it. Lazy loading would be a nice to have, but as it stands now I would discourage you from using monkeypatch plugins for this.

Another option would be to create a SQL view which would only contain the lightweight fields and run your ops from there.

Comment: I'm not having any big blob tables, but a very busy site with highly dynamic caching, so even fragment caching can't be done. So I thought when I only load the primary key from the main database and everything else by using a key/value store (memcache, ..) I could scale much better while still having all data in the db and so being able to maintain proper integrity using foreign keys etc.